# Trying to read JSON data from a JSON planetary API

Tags: c#, json, api

I am try to read data from this JSON file http://www.astro-phys.com/api/de406/states?date=1000-1-20&bodies=mars the date reads fine but I want to read :

`[-168045229.22750974, 164411532.90034229, 80245103.265201837]`

But as the data doesn't have a name I don't know how. This is my current code

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Planets

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filecontents;
            string pagerequest = "http://www.astro-phys.com/api/de406/states?date=1000-1-20&bodies=mars";

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@pagerequest);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
            string html = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                filecontents = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Results results = jsonSerialiser.Deserialize<Results>(filecontents);
            richTextBox1.Text = (results.date);
            Console.Write(results.date);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Results
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public Position position { get; set; }
    }


    //public class Position
    //{
    //    public int x { get; set; }
    //    public int y { get; set; }
    //}
}
```

I am brand new to this and any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Results` class should look something like this

```
public class Results
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, IList<decimal[]>> results { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
}
```

This allows for multiple planetary data points to be defined in the JSON.
i.e. if you were to call `http://www.astro-phys.com/api/de406/states?date=1000-1-20&bodies=mars,earth` would return mars and earth etc.

Then to access a specific co-ordinates

```
var coord1 = results.results["mars"][0][0]; // -168045229.22750974
var coord2 = results.results["mars"][0][1]; // 164411532.90034229
var coord3 = results.results["mars"][0][2]; // 80245103.265201837
```